# Código mysql no viewreport

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2015, reportviewer

Boa noite, estou tentando criar um report, porém que, por exemplo... Tenho uma tabela propriedade e nela tem o id, o nome e afins... e tenho a tabela animal que está salvo nela apenas o id da propriedade e gostaria que no momento que mostrasse o report tivesse como fazer um código para selecionar o nome da propriedade da tabela propriedade e mostrar no report... além de só aparecer os animais pertencentes ao usuario que está logado. Teria como fazer isso? Alguém me ajuda? Estou com problemas... Y.Y

Comment: Não entendi muito bem qual é seu problema, poderia editar a pergunta e ser mais especifico? Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) também para aprender como o site funciona.